# Como inserir o dado em um campo específico de uma tabela _mysql_?

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada empresa, com os campos *nome*, *endereco*, *cidade*, *telefone*, *email* e *link*.

Como devo proceder para inserir um valor no campo *link* que está vazio?

Comment: O que vc quer saber é qual comando SQL usar?

Answer (score 4):

Você pode executar um `UPDATE`, mas cuidado ! pelo visto você não tem um `ID` único para cada campo. Eu fiz o `UPDATE` selecionando pelo nome, e isso não está correto nessa ocasião, porém vai funcionar, você pode alterar pelo campo que você deseja selecionar, segue o código:

```
UPDATE empresa
SET link = 'https://seusite.com'
WHERE nome = 'Leonardo'
```

***A FORMA CORRETA DE SE FAZER***

Uma tabela com `auto_increment` e uma chave Primaria.

```
CREATE TABLE empresa(
   ID int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   nome varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   endereco varchar(255),
   cidade varchar(255),
   telefone varchar(255),
   email varchar(255),
   link varchar(255),
   PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

Para dar `INSERT`, é a mesma coisa da sua tabela, porém não precisa setar o `ID` pois ele é automático.

O UPDATE ficaria assim:

```
UPDATE empresa
SET link = 'https://seusite.com'
WHERE ID = 1
```

Sendo assim, você não mudaria a cidade de TODOS os Leonardo, apenas do Leonardo com `ID = 1` que é único.

Answer (score 1):

`UPDATE "table" SET link = "value" WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

Dessa forma você já conseguiria atualizar este dado, mas como o Leonardo citou, uma tabela sem ID é preocupante !

```
UPDATE empresa
SET link = 'https://link.com'
WHERE nome = 'Linhares'
```

Comment: Mas não tem problema, só existe apenas uma tabela, por isso não há a necessidade de ID, entendeu????

Comment: Entendo, de qualquer forma isso se chama boas praticas, como você disse, por ser uma unica tabela provavelmente não fará falta, mas tirando isso você pode utilizar qualquer outro campo na clausula where e executar o update na coluna link ou como desejar (y)